# Can the average of a function be defined as the sum of its image over its cardinality?

Tags: definition, average

In practice, when calculating the average, this is essentially  what you are doing. You are summing up an infinite number of function values (the functions image), and dividing by that infinite number (the cardinality of the set that contains the functions image). So is this statement correct? I haven't seen it stated this way anywhere, so I am unsure if it is correct.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio care to elaborate...?

Comment: The point is that (1) it isn't clear how you would extend the real numbers / complex numbers / various vectors in a way that makes the arithmetic of $\Bbb R$ a restriction of cardinal arithmetic, nor if it's actually desirable; (2) cardinal arithmetic has trivial multiplication and sum (namely $\alpha\kappa=\alpha+\kappa=\max\{\alpha,\kappa\}$ for all infinite cardinals) and therefore there isn't an effective notion of division there.